# Plain and para footnotes appearing at the bottom of each page in their natural order

Tags: footnotes, manyfoot, para

Currently, with a package like 'manyfoot', I can have different levels of footnotes where each level is grouped together but this is not the result I need.

Suppose that `\footnoteA` produces plain footnotes and `\footnoteB` produced para footnotes. I wish my footnotes to appear in the natural order they appear in my document. For instance, if I have

```
\footnoteA{First}
\footnoteB{Second}\footnoteB{Third}
\footnoteA{Fourth}
\footnoteB{Fifth}\footnoteB{Sixth}\footnoteB{Seventh}
```

I need my footnotes to appear as

```
1) First
2) Second 3) Third
4) Fourth
5) Fifth 6) Sixth 7) Seventh
```

at the bottom of page. Is this possible?

An example using `manyfoot` package but not producing my desired result would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\begin{document}

\footnoteA{First}
\footnoteB{Second}\footnoteB{Third}
\footnoteA{Fourth}
\footnoteB{Fifth}\footnoteB{Sixth}\footnoteB{Seventh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Is the numbering what you really want?  It looks rather odd, but I'm not familiar with this style of footnotes.  Also, please expand your code into a small, compilable example that produces what you're getting now, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end {document}`.  That way a potential helper can copy and paste it to experiment.

Comment: the numbering looks quite odd. How should a reader find such a footnote?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I edited my question.

Comment: @ulrikefischer I edited my question.